# Only last selected row is focused

Tags: css, angularjs, ui-grid

When i check and select a row in ui-grid, only the last selected row is focused (painted with background).
Are all rows should be painted by default?
thanks

Comment: Only one input element can be focused at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Only one input element can be focused at any time.

Consider using the `:checked` pseudo-class:

```
/* Matches any checked/selected radio, checkbox, or option */
:checked {
  margin-left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

For more information, see

- [MDN CSS Reference - :checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)
- [MDN CSS Reference - :focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Comment: OP also states _"(painted with background)"_, and that could very well be a _row_ with many inputs, it all depends on how things are setup, which makes this answer not very useful and at best a simple guess. Please don't answer such low quality question, when they lack both a proper description and a verifiable sample.